# How to view the images stored in internal memory android

Tags: android, image

I have set of images downloaded from server.I have saved the images in internal memory by following this link

> http://connectcoders.blogspot.in/2012/12/save-bitmap-in-internal-and-external.html.

It is successfully saved in internal memory.How do i view the image manually.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what do you mean by `manually` ???

Comment: I want to view the images.How to do that.

Comment: Have you got any code? Have you tried?

Comment: I just want to view the images which are stored in the device.I have searched but no result.